# How to use groupby objects to get sums of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm playing with an mlb data set from the web to help learn.
The dataframe looks like

```
    Player             Position          Salary     Year
0   Mike Witt          Pitcher           1400000    1988
1   George Hendrick    Outfielder        989333     1988
2   Chili Davis        Outfielder        950000     1988
3   Brian Downing      Designated Hitter 900000     1988
4   Bob Boone          Catcher           883000     1988
.
. 
.
```

As an experiment, I'm trying to find the pitcher that has accumulated the highest total salary through their career. `mlb` is the dataframe.

So far I have tried:

```
mask = mlb.Position == "Pitcher"
pitchers = mlb[mask]
pitcher_groups = pitchers.groupby("Player")
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with the groupby object. I know I need to find the salary sum in each group, and do some sort of comparison... How do I do this without for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
pitcher_groups['Salary'].sum()
```

This sums the salary column on the groupby object.

```
In [57]:

df[df['Position']=='Pitcher'].groupby('Player')['Salary'].sum()
Out[57]:
Player
Mike Witt    1400000
Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the following:

```
pitcher_groups = pitchers[['Player','Salary']].groupby('Player', sort=True).sum()
```