# Pandas Dataframes: How to groupby on a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to generalize the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371988/how-to-use-groupby-objects-to-get-sums-of-other-columns).

The `mlb` dataframe looks like

```
    Player             Position          Salary     Year
0   Mike Witt          Pitcher           1400000    1988
1   George Hendrick    Outfielder        989333     1988
2   Chili Davis        Outfielder        950000     1988
3   Brian Downing      Designated Hitter 900000     1988
4   Bob Boone          Catcher           883000     1988
5   Bob Boone          Catcher           883000     1989
6   Frank Smith        Catcher           993000     1988
7   Frank Smith        Pitcher           1300000    1989
```

Note that the same player may be listed multiple times for different years.
I'm trying to find *the player with maximum total salary for each position.*
Output should be something like:

```
    Position           Player            Salary    
 0  Pitcher            Mike Witt         1400000
 1  Outfielder         George Hendrick   989333
 2  Brian Downing      Designated Hitter 900000
 3  Catcher            Bob Boone         1766000
```

I think I need to do something like group by Position, then group by Player, then sum for each player and find the maximum. But I'm having trouble doing this.

Once I do `positions = mlb.groupby("Position")` I'm having trouble doing the next step. I think a nested groupby by Player is necessary, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What if it is the same name but different position in two different years?

Comment: I'm not going to worry about that. Same player at two positions can just represent 2 different players.

Comment: Put up test data that exercises everything you're trying to do -- maybe all Pitchers, but different incomes over different years with different sums.

Answer (score 2):

This is messy but gets the job done.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['Mike Witt','George Hendrick','Chili Davis','Brian Downing','Bob Boone','Bob Boone'],
                'Position':['Pitcher','Outfielder','Outfielder','Designated Hitter','Catcher','Catcher'],
                'Salary':[1400000,989333, 950000,900000,883000,900000],
                'Year':[1988,1988,1988,1988,1988,1988]})

gp = df.groupby(['Player','Position']).sum()['Salary'].to_frame().reset_index()
gp.sort('Salary',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Position')
```

OR

```
gp.groupby('Position').max()
```

Like @dawg mentioned, this will essentially treat a player that has multiple positions as different players so their salaries per position are what is shown here.

```
            Player           Position   Salary
0        Bob Boone            Catcher  1783000
4        Mike Witt            Pitcher  1400000
3  George Hendrick         Outfielder   989333
1    Brian Downing  Designated Hitter   900000
```

Comment: That doesn't take into account the fact that the same player may be listed multiple times for different years. I want their total earnings, not the maximum salary in one year.

Comment: This does seem to work, but it *does* seem messy. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way. I'm only trying to do this as an exercise, since it seems like a problem that will come up often. I'd be surprised if there was not a cleaner solution using `aggregate` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
g = df.groupby(['Position', 'Player']).aggregate({'Salary': sum, 'Player': lambda y: np.unique(y)})
print g.max(level=['Position'])
```

Comment: This seems to be concatenating Player names because of `aggregate({'Salary': sum, 'Player': sum})`. But if I remove `'Player': sum` then the Player names are lost.

Comment: Edited the answer, but not as clean.

Comment: The salary totals look correct but I don't think it is producing the correct player names.

Comment: Frank Smith is really ruining everything